# How to make UIView animation sequence repeat and autoreverse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

How to make this complex animation repeat and autoreverse?
Is there any way to add options UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat to this animation sequence?

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

        someView.frame = someFrame1;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

            someView.frame = someFrame2;

        } completion:nil];

    }];
```

Comment: Do you want to use keyframeanimation? Keyframe animation has such properties of autoreverse and auto repeat.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To animation from point 1 to 2 to 3 to 2 to 1 and repeat, you can do use `animateKeyframesWithDuration` in iOS 7 and later:

```
someView.frame = frame1;
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        someView.frame = frame2;
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        someView.frame = frame3;
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

If using auto-layout, you can animate the changing of the constraint constants:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        topConstraint.constant = 200;
        leftConstraint.constant = 200;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        topConstraint.constant = 100;
        leftConstraint.constant = 300;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

Or, the approach with auto layout is to deactivate the constraints, and then you can animate using `frame` values or what have you.

---

In earlier versions of iOS, you can use `CAKeyframeAnimation`, for example to animate along a path:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 200.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 300.0)];

CAKeyframeAnimation *animatePosition = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animatePosition.path = [path CGPath];
animatePosition.duration = 1.0;
animatePosition.autoreverses = YES;
animatePosition.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[self.someView.layer addAnimation:animatePosition forKey:@"position"];
```

You can do this with however many points you want. This also useful technique if you want to animate along a curved path (e.g. a circle or bezier curve).

---

To just animate between two points, you can use `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`, such as:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     // do whatever animation you want, e.g.,

                     someView.frame = someFrame1;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

This animates the movement of `someView` from the starting frame to `someFrame1` and back.

By the way, using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` in conjunction with `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` and `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` will give you a smoother effect as the animation reverses and repeats.

Comment: Before asking this question i tried to paste 2 block from the question in the animation block with options Autoreverse and Repeat. This doesn't work

Comment: How do you terminate a repeating animation started in such a manner, for example when the parent view controller disappears?

Comment: Once the view is removed from the view hierarchy, the animation automatically stops and no further action is required on your part (it's not like repeating timer or display link in which you have to clean it up yourself). If you did want to stop a repeating animation, though, you could call `removeAllAnimations` on the view's layer.

Comment: For simplicity: I have a grey bar that my animation turns to blue, then green  with "Okay" in text, and then no text / back to blue and then the original grey. I used the above AutoReverse to achieve this with fewer steps and it worked. However, after it reverses and eventually turns grey again, it then finishes by going back to the animated state of green with the text "Okay". Why is it doing this!? Why doesn't it finish in the original state of just grey?

Comment: Actually i am newbie. I was trying to load the animation in viewdidload. That was the problem. Its working now. Forgot to post it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4 for simple wiggle sequence:

```
func animateWiggle() {
    // Set animation props
    let scaleDelta = CGFloat(0.10)

    // Set transforms
    let wiggleOutHorizontally = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0 + scaleDelta, y: 1.0)
    let wiggleOutVertically = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0 + scaleDelta)

    // Run animation sequence
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        // Animate wiggle horizontally
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.transform = wiggleOutHorizontally
        })

        // Animate wiggle vertically
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.transform = wiggleOutVertically
        })
    },
    completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    UIImageView *pin = [UIImageView new];
    [pin setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 160, 30, 60)];
    [pin setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [holderView addSubview:pin];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                        // [pin setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 20)];
                         [pin setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 200, 60, 100)];
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
```

Comment: (insert your own animation)