# How to make an object rotate infinitely

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to figure out how I can make this last forever. Right now it lasts 1 sec.

```
extension UIView {
func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 20, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration

    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }
    self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: How are you calling this?

`self.rotate360Degrees(duration: 2, completionDelegate: nil)`

And it runs for 2 seconds exactly.

Comment: Try converting the answer here to Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730460/how-to-make-uiview-animation-sequence-repeat-and-autoreverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in :

`rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float(CGFloat.max)`

Or to reverse and repeat :

`rotateAnimation.autoreverse = true` // Though this is probably not what you need.

This gave me a forever rotating box.

```
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.autoreverses = true
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float(CGFloat.max)
```

Comment: Thanks gran_profaci! It works, and I was actually looking for how I could reverse it. Thank you so much !

Comment: For some reason I'm having trouble implementing the autoreverse though. How would go about that? If I just add it, it will give me an error.

Comment: Updated solution. That reverses it too.

Comment: Actually, something strange is happening now. It's rotating 360 degrees to one side, then its reversing then its reversing again and it's doing that all the time..

Comment: Yup... because what it is doing is : 

Going one direction. Finishing this animation.
Then going the opposite.
And so on...

Comment: Hours of searching. You are a hero!